# Laravel (phpredis) will not connect with password (AWS Elasticache)

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

I have a Redis 6.x instance on AWS Elasticache. It is clustered, and has in-transit encryption. I also have a RBAC set up (User with a password in AWS). I am able to connect using the `redis-cli` and then authorize using `AUTH <password>` and it works great. (It uses Redis 6 ACL feature)

However when I add the password to my Laravel configuration I get the error:

> Couldn't map cluster keyspace using any provided seed

If I remove the password from the User in Elasticache, Laravel connects fine and uses Redis perfectly.

Here is my configuration. The password is correct in my env file and because of clustering, is added both in default connection and in the options['parameters'] key.

```
'redis' => [

        'client' => 'phpredis',
        'cluster' => true,

        'clusters' => [
            'default' => [
              [
                'scheme' => 'tls',
                'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
                'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
                'database' => 0,
              ],
            ],

            'options' => [
                'cluster' => 'redis',
            ],
        ],


        'options' => [
            'parameters' => [
                'scheme' => 'tls',
                'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            ],
            'ssl' => ['verify_peer' => false],
            'context' => [],
        ],

    ],
```

I've seen this error before but it seems like it occurs whenever something bad happens, rather than giving me specifics. For example, if I remove the password, and restrict some of the access permissions like SET or READ/WRITE commands, then I also get the same error, and so it is very hard to decipher what the error is.

Comment: same issue here? Were you able to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Laravel 5 or 6?

Our setup is similar to yours, but this solution only seems to work with Laravel 6, but when I use this same configuration, I get the same issue as you in Laravel 5.

```
'redis' => [
    'client' => 'phpredis',
    'cluster' => true,
    'options' => [
        'cluster' => 'redis',
        'ssl' => ['verify_peer' => false],
        'context' => [],
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'parameters' => [
            'scheme' => env('REDIS_SCHEME', 'tls'),
        ],
    ],
    'clusters' => [
        'default' =>
            [
                [
                    'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
                    'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
                    'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
                    'database' => env('REDIS_DATABASE', 0),
                    'persistent' => true,
                ],
            ],
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => 'redis',
        ]
    ],
],
```

Now to figure out how to make my Laravel 5 app work, (Or I'll just have to upgrade my Laravel Apps).